# For loop based kernel vs If statement Kernel - Cuda

Tags: c++, cuda, kernel, gpu, nvidia

I have seen the Cuda Kernel started two separate ways:

1.

```
for (uint32_t i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; i < length; i += blockDim.x * gridDim.x)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

2. 

```
if(i < length)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Both versions are launched with `kernel<<<num_blocks, threads_per_block>>>` where the threads per block are maximized for our device (1024) and the number of blocks (2) for a length of 1025, for example.

The obvious difference is that the for loop allows the kernel to loop when the kernel is launched with less threads, for example 512 threads with 2 blocks length of 1025 it loops twice.

From previous research I've gathered that Nvidia suggests that we do not try and load balance ourselves (read as loop within the kernel like this), for instance, giving a kernel less threads or less blocks to reserve space for other kernels on the device because the load balancing that is built in is supposed to handle this in a more globally optimized way.

So my question is why would we want to use the `for` loop vs the `if` statement form of kernel? Is there a benefit to either at run time?

Given my understanding of Nvidia's stance on load balancing, the only value I can see is the ability to debug synchronously via 1 thread and 1 block setting `<<<1, 1>>>` when we launch the kernel in the `for loop` version or not having to precompute the # of blocks needed (and/or threads).

This is the test project I ran:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>

__global__
inline void kernel(int length)
{
    int counter = 0;
    for (uint32_t i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; i < length; i += blockDim.x * gridDim.x)
    {
        printf("%u: | i+: %u | tid: %u | counter: %u \n", i,  blockDim.x * gridDim.x, threadIdx.x, counter++);
    }
}

__global__
inline void kernel2(int length)
{
    uint32_t i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(i < length)
        printf("%u: | i+: %u | tid: %u | \n", i,  blockDim.x * gridDim.x, threadIdx.x);

}

int main()
{
    //kernel<<<2, 1024>>>(1025);
    kernel2<<<2, 1024>>>(1025);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

Comment: You are right, there is no real benefit because X and Y dimensions can be very large. It may be necessary for large Z dimensions though. It may also come up when porting from other architectures, e.g. OpenCL on intel CPUs wants large thread blocks in the X dimension because it vectorizes along that axis.

Comment: Loops can help to reduce the use of resources (though it typically reduces the amount of parallelism). It can also help to increase the efficiency of the kernel by reducing the time taken by initializations or reductions. For example, when shared memory is used, basic kernels can take a significant time to fill it so to then use it only once. In some cases, the shared memory content can be reused for multiple iteration. For reductions, a thread-local reduction is always faster than using atomics. For very small kernels, the initializing the kernel takes a non-negligible time.

Comment: The [CUDA Pro Tip: Write Flexible Kernels with Grid-Stride Loops](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-pro-tip-write-flexible-kernels-grid-stride-loops/) blog post describes the pros.

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is why would we want to use the for loop vs the if statement form of kernel? Is there a benefit to either at run time?

Yes, there is. Every CUDA thread needs to:

1. Read all of its parameters from constant memory
2. Read grid and thread information from special registers: blockDim, blockIdx, threadIdx (or at least their `.x` components)
3. Do the arithemtic for computing its global index.

That takes a bit of time. It's not a lot; but if your kernel is very simple (e.g. something like adding up two arrays), then - yes, that has a cost. And of course, if you perform your own preliminary computation that is used with all items in the sequence - each thread has to take the time to do that as well.

> From previous research I've gathered that Nvidia suggests that we do not try and load balance ourselves (read as loop within the kernel like this)

I doubt that. The question of whether to iterate a large sequence with a single "CUDA thread" per item or with less threads, each working on multiple items, depends on what is done for individual items in the sequence.